# VS22 python - txt file in project and labeled as content cannot be found

Tags: python, visual-studio-project

I've been receiving this error for quite some time on a few assignments.

```
  Message=[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'frankenstein.txt'
  Source=C:\Users\richy\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\CIS 521\CIS 521\CIS 521\Homework8\homework8.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\richy\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\CIS 521\CIS 521\CIS 521\Homework8\homework8.py", line 171, in create_ngram_model
    with open(path, "r") as f:
  File "C:\Users\richy\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\CIS 521\CIS 521\CIS 521\Homework8\Test.py", line 72, in <module>
    m = create_ngram_model(1, "frankenstein.txt"); m.random_text(15)
```

The file is within the solution explorer project and the build action is content.  I've found a workaround in which I create string variable of the path but I would like to understand why it cannot locate the file and how to correct this issue.

`test_text = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'frankenstein.txt')`

Comment: The value of  `path` in the istruction `with open(path, "r") as f:`?

Comment: Is `frankenstein.txt` in the folder `C:\Users\richy\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\CIS 521\CIS 521\CIS 521\Homework8`?

Comment: The value `path` is the `frankenstein.txt` which is in the folder MattDMo pointed out.

Comment: @frankfalse my comment above answered your question.

Comment: @MattDMo my comment above had also answered your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a file `frankenstein.txt` with the following content:

```
frankenstein
```

The file `frankenstein.txt` is in the folder `C:\Users\richy\OneDrive\Documents\Python Scripts\CIS 521\CIS 521\CIS 521\Homework8`.
I have executed the code below:

```
path = "C:\\Users\\richy\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\CIS 521\\CIS 521\\CIS 521\\Homework8\\frankenstein.txt"

with open(path, "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

The code prints `frankenstein` so it finds the file `frankenstein.txt`.

Obviously I don't have created the file `frankenstein.txt` in your path, but in a folder inside the `documents` directory of my user in my Windows system. In my opinion this difference is not relevant.

Pay attention to your path. Are you sure that there are 3 subfolder `CIS 521` in the path?